# How to deploy a python project?

Tags: python, deployment

I have a python project with a UI that I made using tkinter and I was wondering If there is a way to deploy it online so other people could use/interact with it without me having to send them the whole project via message. Is it right for to be looking at this option given the language or should I change the language given the intent?

Comment: Tkinter is a *desktop* UI, if you want a web app you'll need to rebuild the UI.

Comment: I did google for “tkinter to flask” and looks like you have a few options there. Check this out: https://www.google.com/search?q=tkinter+to+flask&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS852US852&oq=tkinter+to+flask&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.7494j0j7&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8.